# Submitting a form gives me The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'claimId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So i have this div in my asp.net MVC3 application where a user can add files,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploadfile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =         "multipart/form-data" })) {
      <input type="button" id="btnBrowse" class="btnAttachments" value="@Lang.btnBrowse" /> 
      <input type="file" style="visibility: hidden;"  id="btnSave_file" name="files[]" multiple/>                
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnAttachments"/>                       
 }
```

when the Submit button is pressed i get the error:
[prt scrn for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol9ff.png)

So it looks to me, the controller calls the function ClaimForm. The reason that could cause this is that the submit form is in another bigger form that calls a view that has the submit form.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

> The reason that could cause this is that the submit form is in another bigger form that calls a view

Yeah, that's the problem. Nested forms aren't supported, nor recommended. Separate the 2 forms out and your code should hit the correct controller action e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClaimForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The thing is, in the web application: there is a claimForm view that calls the CLaimOverview view, which then calls the NewClaimDetails view that holds the uploadfile form. So there is no possibility to split this up.

Comment: @justauser is it a wizard type app your trying to write? "*There is no possibility to split this up*" - of course there is, in fact, it *has* to be split up otherwise it won't work.